# How to perform Incremental data Update(Bulk Json files ) process using API Calls in Talend

Tags: json, api

Requirement is have bulk Json files(source:SFTP SERVER) with same meta data to implement Incremental data process Using API's, the target is Oracle DB, using Date column as Key. If incoming file size exceeds more than 15mb or file with no data need reject the fileand send email notification.
Can any one help us how to implement in Talend v7.1 with scenario, it is very helpful to me.

Thanks,
Shree

Comment: Yes can help you in this. But need detailed requirement. Will provided you some of the key points

Comment: We have loaded historical data from Json Files(Source: SFTP Server) into Oracle DB using Talend Etl. On top of that the requirement is we need to implement the daily incremental using API's in Talend. Actually i'm not aware of API's how to deal with and also i'm not aware of how to call the incremental data through API's. Please can you help me out  with sample scenario.

Thanks
shree

Comment: Can you share me the sample data and your existing design?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps,

1. Check the count of the file using nb_line method. If the count of file is 0 then redirect it to send mail using trigger --> run if 
   or you can perform this operation using unix command as well.
2. Create a flow to load Json file to Oracle table.
3. Use same Oracle table as a lookup (please use outer join) and using Date column identify the new records are loaded it to the target.